# Discrete random variables with non-negative values

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a random discrete variable with non-negative values. Let $X_1, X_2, X_3$ be independent random variables that have same distribution as $X$. 
Let $T = \min\{n \in \mathbb{N}; X_n \neq 0 \}$
I need to calculate the distribution of $X_T$.

I have only idea of how to start with the exercise: I need to find a common distribution function of $X_t$ and $T$.

May I ask you at which field of probability this exercise belongs?
If the topic is not proper, you can remove this post.

Answer (score 2):

If $0\not\in A$, then
$$
\Pr(X_T\in A) = \Pr(X\in A\mid X\ne0) = \frac{\Pr(X\in A)}{1-\Pr(X=0)}.
$$

Proof:
\begin{align}
\Pr(X_T\in A) & = \mathbb E(\Pr(X_T\in A\mid T)) \\[8pt]
& = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \Pr(X_n\in A\mid T=n)\Pr(T=n) \\[8pt]
& = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \Pr(X\in A\mid X\ne0)\Pr(T=n) \\[8pt]
& = \Pr(X\in A\mid X\ne0)\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Pr(T=n) \\[8pt]
& = \Pr(X\in A \mid X\ne 0).
\end{align}
The reason we can pull the conditional probability out of the sum is simply that it doesn't change as $n$ changes.

Comment: I would be really thankful if you would give also a proof, if you'll have time. How did the colleague (the post has been deleted) come to the geometric distribution?

Comment: The probability distribution of the number of independent Bernoulli trials needed to get one success, with an equal probability of success on each trial is a geometric distribution.